# set the constraint of UICollectionView and UICollectionViewCell but does not display correctly

Tags: ios, iphone

set the constraint of UICollectionView and UICollectionViewCell but does not display correctly

UICollectionView

UICollectionViewCell

Display

UICollectionViewCell does fit the screen width

Yourc ommetnwelcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes...because its Xib....you can create constraints to the xib objects...but what about xib edges....you need to give height and width constraints to your xib to get rid of this...It just placed in your view with xib height and width...in your case it is (340,325)...you have to make it screen width and height what ever you want

Answer (score 0):

If your auto layout constraints within your nib and your collection view are all correct, you shouldn't have to resize anything to make it work. Instead, make sure you're setting the correct size of the cell in the collection view's view controller using UICollectionViewLayout's cellSize property. If your collection view cell, for instance, is a different point size on an iPhone 6 v and iPhone 6+, the resizing the nib will not give you an expected result.